# Where to set responseType to http GET for HttpClient in angular

Tags: angular

I have a service that makes an http call to my backend:

```
exportSubs(param: Param): Observable<Sub[]> {
    return this.http.get<Sub[]>(
      `${environment.apiBaseUrl}/blah`,
      {headers: this.httpUtil.getReqHeaders})
      .catch(error => this.httpUtil.handleError(error));
  }
```

where do I set responseType?

Comment: in the headers like normal

Comment: @mast3rd3mon that's absolutely not what you normally do! Do you mean in the same object as the headers?

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data)? They show exactly where to set it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes it is what you do, its the `Accept` header, unless he means what the angular http response type is, in which case it is already set to an array of `Sub`

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I think you misunderstand the question, I'd suggest also reading the docs I just linked.

Comment: i dont think i do misunderstand at all

Comment: @mast3rd3mon well you're talking about the `Accept` header and the OP is talking about the Angular `HttpClient`'s `responseType` option, so...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify that the data to be returned is not a JSON using the [`responseType`](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data). See the Requesting non JSON data

In your example, you should be able to use:

```
return this.http.get(
    `${environment.apiBaseUrl}/blah`, { responseType: 'text' })
```

EDIT

You can set the responseType as blob,

```
return this.http.get(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/blah`, { responseType: 'blob' });
```

Comment: That's not even valid syntactically, so I doubt you tried it.

Comment: then I get error: "Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3."

Comment: @Drew13 sounds like youre passing an extra parameter into the call, `get` methods only take 2 paramaters, the url and optional http options

Comment: @mast3rd3mon yeah I had to get rid of where I set my headers. I need my responseType to be of type 'blob'.  I'll just figure it out

Comment: you can set the type as blob

Comment: @Sajeetharan that gives me  
Argument of type '{reponseType: 'blob;'} is not assignable to parameter type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | {[header: string]: string | string[]: }; observe?: "body"; params?:

Type '"blob"' is not assignable to type '"json"'

Comment: @Drew13 you need to read the API documentation, and the http guide. If the response type is a blob, there's no way the generic type can be Sub[]: your request is supposed to return a blob, not a JSON array of Subs.

Comment: is there anyway I can set { responseType: 'blob' } and { responseType: 'text ' } together, as my error response is not able to work with blob

Answer (score 0):

All we need to tell that we want a response as "text" and pass while calling api.

```
HTTPOptionsForText: Object = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
   responseType: 'text'
}


 public getHealthCheckStatus() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.config.healthCheckUrl,
        this.HTTPOptionsForText);
  }
```

> The full list of options for responseType is:

- json (the default)
- text
- arraybuffer
- blob